# How to search history for file name given by mask, and located anywehere?

Tags: git

I'd like to find commits containing file "foo.*" in any subdirectory.
Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

You can call following command:

```
$ git log --all --full-history -- **/*.css 
commit a9d919629
Author: Some Author
Date:   Wed Oct 5 17:12:00 2016 -0400

    commit message 1

commit abb09b06d
Author: Some Author Authour
Date:   Tue Sep 15 23:05:12 2015 +0200

    commit message 2

commit 3da5e0efd
Author: Some Author
Date:   Sat Sep 5 20:52:55 2015 +0200

    commit message 3
```

And then using a commit id list committed files:

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r a9d919629
css/flags.css
css/flags/flags.png
cv.html
```

Comment: Am I wrong if I say that this passes all css files from local tree to git and it looks only for them? If YES, this doesn't do that is expected. The search should have nothing to do with current files location. They may even don't exist at all.